# What's the most concise syntax to check chained return values in PHP?

Tags: php

If I need to access a value at the end of a chain of getters like this:

```
$employeeFirstName = $company->getEmployee()
    ->getName()
    ->getFirstName()
    ->getSomethingElse()
    ->getEtc();
```

If name, first name, something else or etc are null subsequent getter calls will throw an exception, so it's common practice to see null checking like this:

```
if($company->getEmployee()
    && $company->getEmployee()->getName()
    && $company->getEmployee()->getName()->getFirstName()
    && $company->getEmployee()->getName()->getFirstName()->getSomethingElse()
    && $company->getEmployee()->getName()->getFirstName()->getSomethingElse()->getEtc()
) {
    // It's safe to use the value of getEtc()
}
```

Is there a more concise/reader-friendly way of null-checking chained get methods like this?

Comment: `so it's common practice to see null checking like this`... is it? O_o

Comment: If it *throws an exception*, you can simply catch that…? Or do you mean it produces an unrecoverable error? FWIW, if the action isn't guaranteed to succeed, you shouldn't be writing it in a fluent style.

Comment: You create a method that performs this long, ugly check and returns the result or error message. `If($company->hasValidEmployee()) { ....` and make the method check whatever it needs to check to ensure valid info is there. Your choice of interface is wrong for this, like @deceze mentioned. If it isn't guaranteed to succeed, don't write it in fluent style.

Comment: @JonStirling Ha, in *this* codebase, at least. :/

Comment: `getName`, `getFirstName`, ..., can returns a null object instead

Comment: @deceze I think try / catch is the solution, but in a lot of these cases, we just don't want to do anything if any of the values don't exist (proceed with the rest of the request), so the exception isn't *handled* per se, just used as a means to prevent a fatal error.

Comment: It depends on what the API is supposed to do. If each method is defined so that it *should* return something, and in **exceptional cases** it won't, then using exceptions is perfectly valid. The calling code handles the exceptional case and goes for an alternative plan instead (use some default value). However, if those cases aren't *exceptional* but rather the norm, you're really abusing exceptions for flow control.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's supposed to be a *fluent API*, none of these methods should return `null` and should instead throw some defined exception. That enables you to write code like this:

```
try {
    $foo = $bar->baz()->quux()->blarg()...;
} catch (FooBarBazException $e) {
    $foo = null;
}
```

If the API is not supposed to be fluent, you should write it step by step with explicit success checks for each step which may return `null`:

```
$baz = $foo->bar()->baz();
if (!$baz) {
    return false;  // or whatever
}

$quux = $baz->quux();
if (!$quux) {
    ...
}

...
```

Repeatedly calling each method with a longer and longer chain is a waste of resources and hard to read.

Comment: Does this apply for JS as well? Coz I have been doing this with checking with `undefined`.

Comment: I'd say one of the two patterns applies to most programming languages, through which is better suited/more preferred depends on the language in question. I would say in JS, exceptions are used less often; but in JS you'd also more often find simple property access instead of method calls and idioms like `((a || {}).b || {}).c`.